# How to show Data coming from API in Grouped List View

Tags: flutter, dart, grouped-list

I have data coming from api like this:

```
   {
        "status": true,
        "error": "",
        "message": "Record Found.",
        "data": {
            "2021-Apr-19": [
                {
                    "img_url": "https://www.rezzap.com/uploads/profile-photo/BWPOFCyHMFm_OgzvCxRwS5dBJTS6wCgy.jpg",
                    "person": "CooperMac",
                    "message": " supported your activity drawing."
                }
            ],
            "2021-Mar-30": [
                {
                    "img_url": "https://www.rezzap.com/uploads/profile-photo/BWPOFCyHMFm_OgzvCxRwS5dBJTS6wCgy.jpg",
                    "person": "CooperMac",
                    "message": " commented on your activity Test Activity 12-11-2020."
                },
              {
                "img_url": "https://www.rezzap.com/uploads/profile-photo/BWPOFCyHMFm_OgzvCxRwS5dBJTS6wCgy.jpg",
                "person": "CooperMac",
                "message": " supported your activity ."
            },
            ],
    }
    }
```

for same I have made Model Like this -:

```
class Support {
  Support({
    this.data,
  });

  Map<String, List<Datum>> data;

  factory Support.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Support(
        data: Map.from(json["data"]).map((k, v) =>
            MapEntry<String, List<Datum>>(
                k, List<Datum>.from(v.map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))))),
      );
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.imgUrl,
    this.person,
    this.message,
  });

  String imgUrl;
  String person;
  String message;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        imgUrl: json["img_url"],
        person: json["person"],
        message: json["message"],
      );
}
```

and Here is the response coming But I don't know How to parse it in model, I need corrections here so if Anyone can help

```
 Future<Support> getSupportActivityData() async {
    final response = await _helper.get(supportedActivityUrl);
    var responseData = response["data"];
    var list = responseData as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Support.fromJson(list);
  }
```

I tried to give return type as  "Future<Map<String, List>>" and others too but it always show me Type cast error

I want to get that data and show it as [List](https://pub.dev/packages/group_list_view/example), so how can I show it here in this grouped List as It asks for key as Header and values as its row?

Answer (score 0):

try this code to convert the map you have first to list

and this can happen from The Backend response or you can convert it from The flutter by

var h=here_the_map_data.forEach((k,v) => here_The_list_variable.add(here_the_map_data(k,v)));

Comment: I'm new to the dart programing this code I have to write where my response is coming (getSupportActivityData) or in the model class? Can u please be precise.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my function with this where response was coming -:

```
  Future<Support> getSupportActivityData() async {
    final response = await _helper.get(supportedActivityUrl);
    return Support.fromJson(response);
  }
```

I already parsed ["data"] in model and what i was doing again parsing data in my repo(where response was coming)